# PHP open curly brace in include file, but not closed

Tags: php

Is it possible to separate `try/catch` block between separate files? For example, I have a page_start.php which opens the try:

```
<?php

    try {
```

and then this file is included at the start of various other files. The page_end.php is included at the bottom to close the try:

```
<?php
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        // Do something here
    }
```

When I try this I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in page_start.php on line X
```

Can this be done?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

It says this:

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

The file is evaluated, so therefore it should contain valid PHP, and not end with an open 'stache. So the answer is no, it cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (at least shouldn't) do such things. If you must do this, it's better to have complete code in one file and include contents of other files inside that block.

```
<?php
try
  {
  require_once('file.php');
  }
catch(\Exception $e)
  {
  }
```